# Debian testing hangs for 180s on boot

Tags: boot, debian, freeze, dmesg

For a while now, my NAS running Debian testing with arch x86_64 constantly hangs for exactly 180s during boot after it has detected all hard drives. I unfortunately ran out of ideas what the cause could be or how I could investigate further what it could be. Is there a way to enable a (more) verbose boot logging that could give me a hint?

My `/var/log/dmesg` is [here](http://paste.debian.net/242089/).

The hang of 180s is around line 1050.

Comment: Have a look at (or post) `/var/log/boot.log`, `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/syslog`. Since the pause happens after `/dev/sdn` is attached, try grepping that in each of these files and check what happens around it: `grep -C 10 sdn /var/log/boot.log`.

Comment: I don't have a `/var/log/boot.log`, but a `/var/log/boot`, which contains absolutely nothing (last file modification is from 2012). `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/syslog` contain exactly the same stuff as dmesg. The log entries in dmesg are identical for all hdds - I think it's just tough luck that the sdn disk is the last disk that is discovered on the sas controller before the delay occurs. There were no special warnings for sdn - since the disk was luckily just a spare, I removed it anyways and made a reboot. The new dmesg is [here](http://paste.debian.net/242089/)